# I'm trying to use PHP to add markers to Javascript (Google Maps) but it isn't working the way I have indended it

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to use PHP to add a custom marker using GET. I can get inside the if statement just fine and the map loads, but this doesn't add a marker, I'm not familiar with Javascript I'm just using the documentation to do what I need to do.

Inside `autolocategmap.js` it just contains the Javascript to initialize the map and use geolocation to find the user and it works great, the only problem is the marker is not appearing on load or refresh or anything, I'm not even sure if I can append this extra bit of script by just including `<script>custom marker</script>`, any information would be great thanks.

```
     <?php
    /* Include header and config and set variable*/
    require_once('config.inc.php');
    require_once($rootdir . $dirsubfolder . 'navbar.php');
    $route = $_GET['route'];
?>

<?php
/* User wants to retrieve their route */
if ((isset($route)) && (strcmp($route, "sunauto") == 0)) { 
?>
<script src="js/autolocategmap.js"></script>
<script>
    addMarker('56.742111','-111.481753','Stop 3', 'Arrives at: 6:00am');
</script>
<?php
}
?>
```

autolocategmap.js:

```
  /**
  * Basic Map
  */

$(document).ready(function(){

 var map = new GMaps({
    div: '#gmap',
   lat: 56.744901,
   lng: -111.473049,
    zoom: 16,
    zoomControl : true,
    zoomControlOpt: {
        style : 'SMALL',
        position: 'TOP_LEFT'
    },
    panControl : false,
  });


    GMaps.geolocate({
  success: function(position) {
    map.setCenter(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
  },
  error: function(error) {
    alert('Geolocation failed: '+error.message);
  },
  not_supported: function() {
    alert("Your browser does not support geolocation");
  }
});

$(window).resize(function () {
   var h = $(window).height(),
   offsetTop = 150; // Calculate the top offset

   $('#gmap').css('height', (h - offsetTop));
   }).resize();
});

function addMarker(lat,lng,title,window){
   map.addMarker({
         lat: lat,
         lng: lng,
         title: title,
         infoWindow: window

      });
}
```

Comment: Just that piece alone doesn't give a lot to work with. Could you show the code from autolocategmap.js where the actual map is created.

Comment: Put the add marker into a function in the js. Then call the function with the coords and text.

Not sure, but the problem could be that the outside script has no idea what 'map' actually is.

Comment: @Rafe How might I call the function with the coords and text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function show_map() {
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 10,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.477118, -0.000732),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
    var checkCoords = new Array();
    checkCoords[0] = addMarker(51.477118, -0.000732, 'Royal Observatory, Greenwich, London', map);
    checkCoords[1] = addMarker(38.92126, -77.066442, 'US Naval Observatory, Washington, DC', map);
    checkCoords[2] = addMarker(48.853499, 2.348090, 'Notre Dame Cathedral, Paris', map);
}

function addMarker(lat, lng, title, map) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        title: title
    });
    marker.setMap(map);
    return (lat + ',' + lng);
}

show_map();
```

Ok, use that for your js file. It is straight javascript, no jQuery, but it does what you want. You can then play with it to your hearts content.

As for multiple markers. There are many ways they can be handled through loading from whatever sources.

Maybe a good bet would be for the php to create a json feed that the javascript could read in and then loop through.

Comment: It's still not showing up, check my code in original post for the updated version thanks.

Comment: How many markers are you looking to add? It might all be simpler for you to do it the old fashioned way of having php actually create the javascript file and send it with a text/javascript content-type header.

Comment: A lot.. 20+, I was thinking of maybe just doing it all inside the js file, but I still want to be able to use that function instead of having to write out the whole thing everytime

Comment: I updated the code for you. It runs fine and can be tailored to your needs by yourself later. Of course, it doesn't have the geolocation bit yet. But you can add that in.